# Get the CurrentLocation instead of LastKnownLocation

Tags: android, android-studio, location

I made this code and it's working, but the location can only be retrieved if I open Google Maps before launching the app. I want to make my app detect my current location instead of the last known location. I found that there is a method called `getCurrentLocation()` that can be used to retrieve my location but I don't know what to put in the parameters. Please help me.

This is my code:

```
private void getLocation() {

    //Check Permissions again
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Reclamation.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Reclamation.this,

                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            requestPermissions(new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_LOCATION);

        }
        
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location LocationGps = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        Location LocationNetwork = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        Location LocationPassive = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);




        if (LocationGps != null) {
            double lat = LocationGps.getLatitude();
            double longi = LocationGps.getLongitude();
            latitude = String.valueOf(lat);
            longitude = String.valueOf(longi);

        } else if (LocationNetwork != null) {
            double lat = LocationNetwork.getLatitude();
            double longi = LocationNetwork.getLongitude();

            latitude = String.valueOf(lat);
            longitude = String.valueOf(longi);

        } else if (LocationPassive != null) {
            double lat = LocationPassive.getLatitude();
            double longi = LocationPassive.getLongitude();

            latitude = String.valueOf(lat);
            longitude = String.valueOf(longi);
            Toast.makeText(Reclamation.this, "Passive is not null :D", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(Reclamation.this, "Can't Get Your Location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Reclamation.this, SetLocation.class);
        intent.putExtra("latt", latitude);
        intent.putExtra("lonn", longitude);
        Toast.makeText(Reclamation.this, latitude + " " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivityForResult(intent, 3);


    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

With

```
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
```

U can use this methods

```
FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
FusedLocationProviderClient locationProviderClient = LocationServices.
                                       getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

//LOCATION AVAILABILITY

fusedLocationClient
            .getLocationAvailability()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<LocationAvailability>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LocationAvailability locationAvailability) {
                    
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    
                }
            });

//LAST LOCATION

 fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    
                }
            });

//AND MORE...

fusedLocationClient
            .requestLocationUpdates()
...
```